# Java threads executing out of order

Tags: java, multithreading

Sometimes, the main method in Java seems to run out of order. Here is an example using threads. The second thread keeps executing first (they are both acting on a synchronized object, so the second thread should wait until the first is done, but instead it executes first).

```
public class Sync {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Child #1", a);
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Child #2", a);

        try {
            mt1.thread.join();
            mt2.thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }
    }
}
```

I first ran the code in an IDE, so I thought that might be the problem, but I got the same result when using command line.

Comment: Post the class `MyThread` please. We can't know what's going on without it.

Comment: please read up java synchronized block

Comment: This code won't do much, since threads mt1 and mt2 are never started.  If you could provide a minimal working example, that would help.

Comment: @WarrenDew We can't know without the class. OP is using `MyThread`, not plain `Thread`, so OP might be starting threads in he constructor of that class...

Comment: Running out of order is what threads do.

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: @BackSlash I suppose that's possible.  If so, of course, that's the first thing he should change.

Comment: So you have two threads that start and contend for a lock. really there is no good reason for the first one to have that much of an advantage, either can get chosen to run first. that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thread are meant to run independently by design which means they can run in any order.

Comment: @NathanHughes's comment looks like the real answer to this question.  The purpose of `synchronized` blocks is to prevent threads from working with the same data at the same time.  It does not serve any other purpose (e.g., in this case, it affords no means for a program to control the order in which the threads run when they race to enter a synchronized block.)

Comment: If you want your program to perform a sequence of operations in a particular order, then the correct way to do it is to perform the operations in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

my interpretation of your question is that you think by calling

```
try {
            mt1.thread.join();
            mt2.thread.join();
    }
```

in the main function, you're expecting thread 1 to execute followed by thread 2.

However, by calling mt1.thread.join(); in the main thread, all it accomplishes is suspend the main function's execution until mt1 finishes execution. This says nothing about whether mt1 executes before, after, or concurrently with mt2. All it could possibly ensure is that the main thread will FIRST wait for mt1, and then wait for mt2.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!